# How can I use a nested for loop to improve this function?

Tags: python, for-loop, nested, generator

I am wondering how I should use a nested for loop to improve the readability of this function. Perhaps I could use a `nested for loop` for `tags_files =`?

```
def search_repotag_for_file(search_filepath, repo):
    '''Goes through all tags, all files to find a github file entity
       which matches the search_filepath we are looking for'''
    all_tags = (tag for tag in repo.tags)
    tags_files = ((tag, file_ent) for tag in all_tags for file_ent in tag.commit.tree.traverse())
    matches = (tup for tup in tags_files if tup[1].path == search_filepath)
    return matches
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me rewrite your function for you:

```
def search_repotag_for_file(search_filepath, repo):
    for tag in repo.tags:
        for file_ent in tag.commit.tree.traverse():
            if file_ent.path == search_filepath:
                yield (tag, file_ent)
```

The keyword you are looking for is [`yield`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do)

Comment: Wow! This is perfect. I came close to this answer, but not exactly. Thanks! :D